# Vanna-Volga consistency result

Tags: volatility-smile, vanna-volga

In the Vanna-Volga (VV) paper by Castagna and Mercurio they state that, once you build up a curve of prices by interpolating-extrapolating on $K$, you can recover the same exact curve by redefining the curve, now using three prices result of using three new different strikes and the VV method:

> We now state two important consistency results that hold for the
> option price (7) and that give further support to the VV procedure.
> The ﬁrst result is as follows. One may wonder what happens if
> we apply the VV curve construction method when starting from
> three other strikes whose associated prices coincide with those
> coming from formula (7). Clearly, for the procedure to be robust,
> we would want the two curves to exactly coincide. This is indeed
> the case. [...]

It's given as a result but its not proven within the paper. Is it just an "empirical" result? Does someone know if this result has been proven analytically somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: The proof is given in Castagna and Mercurio, Consistent pricing of FX options. (Risk articles sometimes omit proofs given constraints on length etc).

Comment: Thanks Frido, I'll check it out!

Comment: Always happy to help out a fellow amateur quant (from your profile) :)